# adding custom made wheel spinner to layout

Tags: java, android, swing, android-layout, android-spinner

In my java application(with Swing) I used a custom made spinner class that extendes JSpinner (which give me the required shape as image attached) ,then used it to  instantiate a spinner object.

Now in my Android version of the application...seems when making the XML layout with Spinner tag and it's attributes, either I couldn’t find a Spinner like that shape or there is none basically.

How to get this Wheel Spinner shape ?

P.S: I’m using Intellij IDEA,  and  Android API 24 .[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use library for this
there are many number pickers library for android
you may try this https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker